# reduce register pressure by passing fixed values as kernel args

Tags: opencl

I am trying to reduce register pressure in my kernel. There are certain fixed values that I am currently calculating, such as the dimensions of the image I am processing; does it make sense to pass these dimensions in as kernel arguments? They are fixed for all work groups. I read somewhere that kernel arguments get special treatment and are not assigned to registers.

Comment: "I read somewhere that kernel arguments get special treatment" Where ? I'm interessted.

Comment: Generally, kernel arguments are in constant memory (if they are not pointers/buffers), so that provides extra speed. But you should declare them as constant to ensure that, otherwise it is implementation specific. Obviusly they will eventually reside in registers(like any other data), but at least the fetch will be faster.

Comment: Thanks, folks. @DarkZeros, please move this comment to the answer section, so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenCL spec mandates that kernel arguments be in the `__private` address space, so in theory kernel arguments may be stored in registers, constant memory, dedicated register file or anything else. In practice, implementations will often put kernel arguments in constant memory (*constant memory*, not `__constant` address space). Constant memory is a read only small memory that GPUs use for broadcasting general data (like camera matrices). They are very fast, much faster than global memory. Similar speed to local memory.

If you pass a value to the kernel, then it will reside in the constant memory. There will be no fetch to global.

However, that data will eventually reside in registers(like any other data) in order to operate with it. You will not save any registers. But at least it will make your kernel run faster.

Comment: so, a kernel argument should be marked with the 'const' keyword? or the __constant keyword ?

Comment: You don't need to declare them `__constant` because kernel args are already in that space (if the compiler is clever enough). In any way it should work properly if you declare them `__constant`.  You should declare them `const` if they are read only, or you plan to write on them later on. You can find more information in https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/constant.html and https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Well, I was wrong. Your answer is better.